# Corrupted font in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, fonts

yesterday suddendly my visual studio 2008 started to render the text in a bad way (only in the source editor, the rest is ok).
I changed my font in the options and the other fonts render fine.
Do you have any idea why Courier New (and only it) starting to be rendered so bad?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Same as [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286196/is-it-just-my-imagination-or-have-the-fonts-gotten-even-uglier)

Comment: The issue seems without a fix....

Comment: Hi just took a look to my system (windows server 2008) and I have no KB3013455 installed....so that cannot be the cause